# Чудотворец Никола или Николай; Банья или Баня при переводе с сербского?

Tags: заимствования

[Баня святого Николы](http://www.pravoslavie.ru/113134.html)

> ...Свое столь близкое нам, но все же необычное для монастыря название
>   Баня (серб. Бања) обитель получила по расположенным на его территории
>   термальным источникам вод, которые обладают целебными свойствами.

---

[Монастырь Банья (серб. Манастир Бања) — монастырь Сербской православной церкви в Сербии, находится в одноимённом селе близ города Прибой. Относится к Милешевской епархии. Монастырь является памятником культуры Сербии большого значения. Предположительно, монастырь Банья был основан в XII веке, тогда его игумен упоминался в «Студенички типике». С 1220 года монастырь был центром Дабарской епископии, в связи с чем именовался «Святой Николай Дабарский».](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%8F_(%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%8C))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если деятель **сербского происхождения**, то имя не переводится: *Никола Тесла*.

Николай Чудотворец - это не сербский святой, нужно писать по-русски.

Банья - название **сербского монастыря**, обязательно сохранить оригинальность названия при переводе.